# dd: different unit for bs, skip and count?

Tags: dd

I am trying to copy a partition from an entire disk image.

This command is working: `dd if=image.iso of=test bs=512 skip=1161215 count=32768`

In order to increase the speed, I'd like to set a bigger `bs`.

`dd if=image.iso of=test bs=1M skip=1161215 count=32768`

`skip` and `count`'s unit is `bs`, is it possible to set a separate unit ?

I could then make this command:

`dd if=image.iso of=test bs=4M skip=1161215*512 bytes count=32768*512 bytes`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible by combining `dd` commands.

`dd if=image.iso bs=4M | { dd bs=1161215 count=1 of=/dev/null; dd bs=${16*512} count=${32768/16} of=partition.dump; }`

We can just use the count size as a dividable without remainder instead of both, offset and size.

Or use the end sectors.

Comment: Interesting approach, very nice idea. But I don't really understand the calculation `${32768/8192}` you made. Did you also test the performance of this? I suspect it could be lower with your pipe and the different block sizes.

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake, divided by 16 since 32768 is the number of 512B's sectors. Lack of time, I didn't try yet, I found this solution unexpectedly. After thinking, you may be right, maybe the first instance of dd which redirects to /dev/null, will take times. But we could imagine another configuration with pipe to remove this processing time.

Answer (score 7):

### Specify Different Units

Yes, it is possible to specifiy different units for `bs` and `skip` and `count`. However, there are only two choices for the `skip` and `count` units. `skip` and `count` must match the `bs` value or be specified in bytes. To set the units to bytes you must add an additional operand of `iflag=skip_bytes` for `skip` and `iflag=count_bytes` for `count` or `iflag=skip_bytes,count_bytes` for both.

In your case, this command should accomplish your goal:

```bash
dd if=image.iso of=test iflag=skip_bytes,count_bytes bs=4M \
  skip=$((1161215*512)) count=$((32768*512))
```

It appears you want to extract exactly 16M. Set `bs=4M count=4` and use only `skip_bytes`:

```bash
dd if=input.file of=output.file iflag=skip_bytes bs=4M \
  skip=$((1161215*512)) count=4
```

### Example for testing:

An input file with the contents:

```
aabbccddeeffgghhiijjkkllmmnnooppqqrrssttuuvvwwxxyyzz
```

With `count_bytes` (extract exactly `count` bytes):

```
$ dd if=input.file of=output.file iflag=skip_bytes,count_bytes bs=8 skip=5 count=20
```

yields 20 characters:

```
cddeeffgghhiijjkkllm
```

Without `count_bytes` (`count` is multiplied by `bs`):

```
dd if=input.file of=output.file iflag=skip_bytes bs=8 skip=5 count=3
```

yields 24 characters:

```
cddeeffgghhiijjkkllmmnno
```

---

Your version of `dd` may not include `iflag`, `skip_bytes`, or `count_bytes`.
These examples were tested on **Debian 9** using **dd (coreutils) 8.26**.

**Update:** `skip_bytes` and `count_bytes` are supported from coreutils [v8.16](https://savannah.gnu.org/forum/forum.php?forum_id=7170)(March 2012), so nearly all distributions will support it by default

Answer (score 1):

What you want to achieve seems impossible to me.

From `man dd`:

```
   bs=BYTES
          read and write up to BYTES bytes at a time

   ibs=BYTES
          read up to BYTES bytes at a time (default: 512)

   obs=BYTES
          write BYTES bytes at a time (default: 512)


   count=N
          copy only N input blocks

   skip=N skip N ibs-sized blocks at start of input
```

While `bs` (or `ibs` and `obs`) has an argument `BYTES` which determines the **block size** i.e. the amount of bytes that gets processed at once, the `count` and `seek` parameters have an argument `N` which determines the **number of blocks** to process/skip.

So as `dd` can always only copy or skip whole blocks of data (block size determined by `bs`/`ibs`&`obs`), you must set the block size to a value by which the `skip` offset and the `count` size are dividable without remainder.

Comment: With your assumption, the quantity of Bytes copied is different for both `dd if=image.iso of=test bs=1M skip=1161215 count=32768` and `dd if=image.iso of=test bs=512 skip=1161215 count=32768`. It means it's correlated.

Comment: @Alexis_FR_JP Sorry, I was obviously wrong before. I researched it again and corrected my mistake. Unfortunately this means you can not do what you wanted to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

> is it possible to set a separate unit?

AFAIK, with `dd` only, no.

but you can use [losetup](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/losetup.8.html) to achieve your goal, like this:

```
dd if=$(losetup --sector-size 512 --offset $((1161215*512)) --sizelimit $((32768*512)) --find --show image.iso) of=test bs=4M
```

or, more concisely, like this:

```
dd if=$(losetup -b 512 -o $((1161215*512)) --sizelimit $((32768*512)) -f --show image.iso) of=test bs=4M
```

---

Even more...

> In order to increase the speed, I'd like to set a bigger bs

if you just want to '*forget about*' "blocksize optimization",
and it's available for you, simply use [pv](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pv.1.html), like this:

```
pv $(losetup -b 512 -o $((1161215*512)) --sizelimit $((32768*512)) -f --show image.iso) > test
```

Comment: I forgot why I needed that, let me try later and approve your answer if it's correct.